# How to hide members / methods of an Angular component in a TypeScript library?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I'm writing a library to provide an Angular component as an NPM package. This library only exports one Angular component and I wonder how I can hide/encapsulate certain methods of my component?

Simplified example:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<button (click)="myMethod()">{{ title }}</button>`,
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() input: any;

  /** @internal */
  title: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.title = 'something';
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    // do something
  }

  public externallyAvailable() {
    // do something
  }

  /** @internal */
  myMethod() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Assume that `myMethod()` and `title` are referenced in the component's template and therefore cannot be declared private. As described [by GregRos in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53124244/4425803), we can use `/** @internal */` in combination with the compiler option `stripInternal` to hide declarations.

Using this approach, I managed to hide `myMethod()` and `title`. If I import my component library in a separate Angular app and reference `MyComponent` as a `ViewChild`, then I can access the public method `externallyAvailable()` but also the methods `ngOnChanges()` and `ngOnInit()`.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponent } from 'my-project';

export class TestComponent {

  @ViewChild('myComponent') myComponent: MyComponent;

  test() {
    this.myComponent.externallyAvailable();
    this.myComponent.ngOnInit();
  }
```

How could I hide `ngOnChanges()` or `ngOnInit()`, too? How do famous component libraries such as Angular Material hide these members / methods?

Adding `/** @internal */` to `ngOnChanges()` or `ngOnInit()` causes errors when I import my library into an Angular application:

```
ERROR in dist/my-project/lib/components/my-component/my-component.component.d.ts:5:22 - error TS2420: Class 'MyComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'OnChanges'.
  Property 'ngOnChanges' is missing in type 'MyComponent' but required in type 'OnChanges'.
```

Comment: maybe I don't fully understand, but aren't all methods in a component basically internal? You can't call a method from outside the component unless you use a ViewChild.

Comment: oh, maybe you're right, that makes sense. What I didn't mention in my question was that I reference `MyComponent` via `ViewChild()` in a separate Angular app. And in this separate Angular app, I can call the method `externallyAvailable()`. But I can also access `ngOnChanges()` and `ngOnInit()` which confuses me.

Comment: @Rick , you were right. I tested it with Angular Material. If I reference a `MatButton` (from Angular Material) via a `ViewChild`, then I can access `ngOnInit()` and `ngOnChanges()`, too. So it looks like I cannot hide these methods or probably don't need to worry about his.