# Is there any way to create 'internal' property in type Script?

Tags: angular, typescript

I write a 'library' in angular and type script. this library distribute as a *.ts package in other angular  workspaces.

In this library I have an export class that contains some properties.
One property in this class should be set in the library only.

TS:

```
export class Bar{
   foo:boolean; // set only in the scope of the library
}
```

Is there a way to declare a property as 'internal' in type script, or any other way to force property to be set only within the scope of library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a Typescript API hide internal members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188679/how-does-a-typescript-api-hide-internal-members)

Comment: Thanks @John for your comment but my library distribute the code as *ts, so it didnt help me.

Comment: I know this is rudimentary, but is using private and protected members out of question ?

Comment: I have to set the property out of the class so protected and private wont help.

Comment: Nope. there is not. Only non exported members are hidden from outside world but it is not usefull on a larger scale.

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks for you response. I dont need the property to be hidden but not to be set, like private set in library only and readonly outside

Comment: There is no TS way of doing that. You can however just SET it. It is javascript after all where everything is accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a way to declare a readonly property that can be set in the library only.

not nice but work:

1. declare a class that not export **outside** the library.

```
export class Foo{
    prop!:boolean;
}
```

2. add `Readonly` property in the main export class

```
export class Bar{
    Foo?:Readonly<Foo>=new Foo();
}
```

3. set the property within the library like so:

```
let bar:Bar=new Bar();
(bar.foo as Foo).prop=true;
```

4. outside the library, you can not set the property.

> Cannot find name 'Foo'.ts(2304)

> Cannot assign to 'prop' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)

[image: Error]